# Function out of scope?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have a function defined as follows:

```
window.onload = function() {
      var ids = document.getElementById("idname");
      function myFunction(){

            /...*use ids var in here*./
      }
}
```

I am trying to call `myFunction` from button `onclick` in html:

```
<button onclick="myFunction();"></button>
```

But it says `myFunction` is not defined. I understand because this is inside `window.onload`. How can I fix this? I need `window.onload` because I need to use `document.getElementById("testID")` to get content.

Comment: You could assign the method to window like `window.myFunction = function() { /*....*/ }`

Answer (score 4):

> I need window.onload because I need to use document.getElementById("testID") to get content

No, you don't need `window.onload`. You simply have to put the code somewhere **after** the element with ID `testID` in the document.

Example:

```
<div id="testID"></div>
<script>
    var ids = document.getElementById("testID");
    function myFunction(){
        /...*use ids var in here*./
    }
</script>
```

However, if you want to keep using `window.onload`, then I suggest to *not* use inline event handlers, but bind the handler with JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var ids = document.getElementById("testID");
    ids.onclick = function(event){
      /...*use ids var in here*./
    }
};
```

(that might be a good thing to do anyway).

Lastly, you can get the a reference to the element inside the event handler using `this` or `event.target`:

```
<div id="testID"></div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("testID").onclick = function(event) {
      // access element via `this` or `event.target`
    };
</script>
```

[Learn more about event handling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Comment: "(that might be a good thing to do anyway)." pretty well sums up what I would have done.

Answer (score 1):

You defined it within a `function` so it's locked to that scope. Maybe you want to define it outside of that:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ids = document.getElementById("idname");
  // ...
}

window.onload = function() {
  // ...
}
```

As a note, this is *extremely* old-school JavaScript. You could clean this up considerably using something like jQuery which would look something like this:

```
$(function() {
  // Any initialization after page load.
});

function myFunction() {
  var ids = $('#idname');

  // ...
}
```